Inserting values into SQL Server CE table with combined primary key causes error
My SQL Server CE table BandsMembers has 2 columns, bandID and MemberID taken from Bands and Roster intending to show which members are in other bands as well as the home band. The BandsMembers table specifies the two columns as combined primary key.
My complete Razor code for the .cshtml page is:
@{
    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\SSB.sdf", "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");  
     Layout = "~/_SiteLayout2.cshtml";    
    var paramMember  = UrlData[0];
    int MemberID = paramMember.AsInt(); 
    var getName = "SELECT MemberID, Roster.firstname + ' ' + Roster.lastname AS Name FROM Roster WHERE MemberID = @0";
    var row = db.QuerySingle(getName, MemberID);
    var Name = row.Name; 
    var bands = db.Query("SELECT bandID, bandName FROM Bands ORDER BY bandName");
    var bandID = 0;
    Page.Title = "Edit Bands for " + @Name;    
  }         

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">     
         function getBandID() {
                var e = document.getElementById("bandID");
                bandID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;                
            }
     </script>
</head>    
<body class="cent">     
    @{        
      <form method="post" name="add">
         <div class="cent">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
               <h3>Edit Bands for @Name</h3>
                  <span><label class="label" style="margin-top:10px;" for="typeId">Select Band to add/delete:</label> </span>
                  <span><select name="bandID" id="bandID" onchange="getBandID();" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <option value="">-- Select Band --</option>
                            { 
                               @foreach(var band in bands)
                               {       
                                  <option value="@band.bandID">@band.bandName</option>                      
                               }
                            }                        
                         </select
              </div>
         </div>         
         <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit" name="button" />
         <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="submit" name="button"
         <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="submit" name="button" />
      </form>
          if (IsPost)
          {      
             if(ModelState.IsValid) 
             {
                if( Request.Form["button"].Equals("Cancel") ){
                   Response.Redirect(@Href("~/ShowBandsMembers"));
                }
                if( Request.Form["button"].Equals("Delete") && bandID != null){
                   var deleteQuery =  "DELETE from BandsMembers WHERE bandID=" + @bandID + " && MemberID = @0";
                   db.Execute(deleteQuery);
                   Response.Redirect(@Href("~/ShowBandsMembers")); 
                }
                if(Request.Form["button"].Equals("Add"))
                {                                  
                    var insertQueryString="INSERT INTO BandsMembers (bandID, MemberID) VALUES (@0, @1)";
                    db.Execute(insertQueryString, bandID, MemberID);
                }               
                Response.Redirect(@Href("~/ShowBandsMembers"));
            }
         }      
     }
     
</body>
</html>
    


This is the error I get when I click the "Add" button:

No mapping exists from DbType System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object] to a known SqlCeType.

I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

Please share all your code. What does db.Execute do?

After changing var bandID to int bandID at the top, I no longer get that error.
